# Django relay filter not working for foreign key field

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

```
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from commodity.models import CommodityItem


class Brand(models.Model):
    # more fields...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    

class CommodityItem(models.Model):

    # more fields...
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Brand', db_index=True)
        
        
class CommodityItemNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CommodityItem
        use_connection = True
        description = 'Represents commodity item'
        filter_fields = {
            'is_online' : ['exact'],
            'brand_id': ['exact']
        }
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node, )
        
all_commodity_item = DjangoFilterConnectionField(CommodityItemNode)
```

**Working**

```
query {
    allCommodityItem(isOnline: true) {
        edges {
            node {
                name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Not Working**

```
query {
    allCommodityItem(isOnline: true, brandId: 1) {
        edges {
            node {
                name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "['{\"brand_id\": [{\"message\": \"Invalid ID specified.\", \"code\": \"\"}]}']",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "allCommodityItem"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "allCommodityItem": null
  }
}
```

What I am missing here?

**Reference:** https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-relay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id as relation like this:

```
class CommodityItemNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        # rest of code
        filter_fields = {
           'is_online' : ['exact'],
           'brand__id': ['exact']
        }
```

And in your query:

```
query {
    allCommodityItem(isOnline: true, brand_Id: "1") {
        edges {
           node {
              name
           }
        }
    }
}
```